# Insert into table which has only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

There's a table with one   column - `MyTable(ID)`, where `ID` is primary key with `identity(1,1)`. How to insert one row into this table by stored procedure?

```
 CREATE PROC MyProc
 AS
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] VALUES()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into mytable default values
```